# Jstree search has an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree, jstree-search

I am trying to add search function to jstree but give me an error: `undefined is not a function`

```
 $('#tree_').jstree({
            'core': {
                'check_callback': true,
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                },
                'search': {},
                'plugins': ["search"],
                'data': {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Explorer.aspx/show",
                    data: function () { return '{"id":"' + $id+ '"}' },
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }
            }
        });

        var to = false;
        $('#tree_search').keyup(function () {
            if (to) { clearTimeout(to); }
            to = setTimeout(function () {
                var v = $('#tree_search').val();
                $('#tree_').jstree(true).search(v);
            }, 250);
        });
```

Firstly, I didn't add `'search': {},` but it does not work both way, every keyup `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)` is written in console.